# Stochastic braids

Tags: pr.probability, gt.geometric-topology, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, braid-groups

I am definitely not a probability guy, but I'd like to have a heuristic answer to the following question: do $n$ independently moving points in an open, connected, bounded region $R$ tend to "braid" a lot?

Here is my toy model. Firstly, if we imagine having $n$ continuous trajectories $\gamma_1, \ldots, \gamma_n : [0, T] \to R$ that does not intersect pairwise, we can define their braiding as the corresponding element of the braid group(oid) in $R$. A simple associated invariant is given by
$$\textrm{#positive crossings - #negative crossings}$$
which is nice because it can be computed by looking at two strands at a time.

For $n=2$, we will assume $R$ to be a cylinder, with strands having a constant velocity in the $z$-axis direction. We can further simplify the model by imagining one strand to be fixed in the center of the disk. We now consider a stochastic process $X$ on the disk and consider the second strand as being $(X(t), t)$. Given my total ignorance about such processes, I will only describe the discrete analog I think (it should be a variation of the 2D Wiener process). At time $t+ \epsilon$, $X$ will choose uniformly in which direction $v \in S^1$ to go, and then
$$ X(t+ \epsilon) = X(t) + \frac{\epsilon v}{\alpha(v, \| X(t) \| )}$$
Where $\alpha(v, r) > 0$ is a weight that incentivizes the process to go toward the center and prevents the process from exiting the disk. I thought about something inspired by the hyperbolic disk but I can't seem to work out a nice formula (it is independent of $v$).

The braid invariant $b(X)$ I mentioned above is a sort of winding number and can be computed in this way. Let $s_1(t), s_2(t) \in \{+,-\}$ be the sign of the projections along the $x$-axis and $y$-axis of the process respectively (not defined when such projections are zero, which happens almost never). Then $b(X)$ gains $+1$ when $X$ passes from $(+,+)$ to $(-,+)$ or from $(-,-)$ to $(+,-)$, and $-1$ when going in the opposite direction. The other two possible switches (that is $(+,+) \leftrightarrow (+,-)$ and $(-,+) \leftrightarrow (-,-)$ ) produce no change in $b(X)$.

In the end, I'd like to know the distribution of $b(X) \in \mathbb{Z}$, if such a thing has a meaning. I expect its mean value to be zero since the process is symmetric under inversion of angles. If you have a better model to suggest, it is more than welcome. Thanks!

Comment: A good place to start would be this paper https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-10/issue-1/A-New-Proof-of-Spitzers-Result-on-the-Winding-of/10.1214/aop/1176993928.full  on the winding number of a planar brownian motion

Comment: Wow, that's incredibly nice. As far as I understand, the probability $P(n,t)$ of having done $n$ windings within time $t$ should asymptotically be $\sim \frac{\log(t)}{4 \pi^2(1+n^2)}$.

Comment: https://people.math.wisc.edu/~thiffeault/talks/gfd2014_notes.pdf

Comment: Trying to separate my headphone cord from a pile of other cords, after gently laying it on the table last night, I was reminded of this question.

Comment: in order to go up one strand, one should be able to study the distribution of $\varphi(X)+\varphi(Y)+\varphi(X+Y)$, where $X,Y$ are two planar Brownian motions and $\varphi$ represents the "winding number" (not necessarily an integer, it represents the number of windings plus the remaining angle in radiants).  The single variables asymptotically obey a Cauchy distribution (times $\log(t)/4 \pi$). One can see that $\tan \varphi(X+Y) = \frac{ ||X|| \cos \varphi(X) + ||Y|| \cos \varphi(Y)}{||X|| \sin \varphi(X)+ ||Y|| \sin \varphi(Y) } $. I don't remember how to "convolve" dependent variables...